# How to maintain Start and End index of DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I have a DataTable which contains 13 rows. I want to create a batch of 5 Rows with start and end index

I want to create a array or Hashtable which will store start and end index

```
decimal remainder = Decimal.Divide(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count, 5);
var numberOfRequests = Math.Ceiling((decimal)remainder);
```

above code will give me the out put as 3 for 13 records means 5+5+3

### So expected an `Array` or `Hashtable` as below

> ```
> 0  0   4
> 1  5   9
> 3 10  12
> ```

First Column is incremental value, 
Second Column is DataTable Row Start index
Third Column is DataTable Row End index

Please suggest me how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{5});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{6});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{7});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{8});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{9});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{11});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{12});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{13});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{14});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{15});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{16});


            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((x,i) => new {index = i, row = x})
                .GroupBy(y => (int)(y.index/5))
                .Select(z => z.Select(a => a.row).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i have one more question. 

can we convert

(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>>(results)).Items[0]

to datatable?

Comment: DataTable dt2 = results[0].CopyToDataTable();